# Woocommerce use array inside custom field to update pricing based on quantity based on quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce

Each product has its own custom field called `'prices'` that includes an array for quantity and bulk pricing - example array:

```
{"USD":[{"unit_break":3000,"unit_price":"0.0850"},{"unit_break":6000,"unit_price":"0.0819"},{"unit_break":12000,"unit_price":"0.0795"},{"unit_break":18000,"unit_price":"0.0771"},{"unit_break":24000,"unit_price":"0.0742"},{"unit_break":30000,"unit_price":"0.0731"},{"unit_break":300000,"unit_price":"0.0719"}]}
```

What I need to do is if the quantity in the cart is less than or equal to each `'unit_break'`, then the price should reflect the `'unit_price'` in the same array column.

Something like this maybe?

```
if cartquantity <= 'unit_break[0]' {
product price = 'unit_break[0]' => 'unit_price[0]
} else if cartquantity <= 'unit_break[1]' {
Product price = 'unit_break[1]' => 'unit_price[1]
}
```

... and so on.

There could be any number of unit breaks per product so these numbers need to be dynamic.

I've tried iterating over each array but I can't figure that out either.

Below is the code I currently have so far, which gets me as far as the first unit_break/unit_price in the array, but nothing after.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'quantity_based_bulk_pricing', 9999, 1 );
function quantity_based_bulk_pricing( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) 
        return;


    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get the bulk price from product custom field
        $prices = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'prices', true);
        $prices = json_decode($prices, true);

        $s = 0;

        foreach($prices as $price) {
            foreach($price as $unit) {
                $bulk_price = $unit['unit_break'];
                $qty_threshold = $unit['unit_price'];
            }
            $bulk_price = $price[$s]['unit_price'];
            $qty_threshold = $price[$s]['unit_break'];

            // Check if  item quantity has reached the defined threshold
            if( $cart_item['quantity'] <= $qty_threshold) {
                // Set the bulk price
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $bulk_price );
            }


            //echo $qty_threshold.'<br>';
            //echo $bulk_price;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `This is as far as I've gotten` - could you explain that more in detail, what works or what does not work? Where are you stuck? Right now you would expect people to read and understand the code without any context.

Comment: @Uwe I've updated my question, hope that helps clarify

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array structure in your example is correct, the code below should work. I am not sure whether the `prices` meta could have multiple currencies within (you only have USD in your example), but if it does, feel free to adjust the code as you wish.

This is the altered code for your main `$cart->get_cart()` foreach loop:

```
// If you have multiple currencies in 'prices' meta, you should set target currency
$target_currency = 'USD';

// Loop through cart items
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    
    // Get prices from post meta
    $prices = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'prices', true);
    $prices = json_decode( $prices, true );
    
    // Get cart item quantity
    $cart_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

    // If 'prices' is defined for this product
    if( $prices ) {
        
        // Loop through each currency
        foreach ( $prices as $currency => $breakpoints ) {

            // If this is not the target currency, continue
            if ( $currency != $target_currency ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Loop through each price breakpoint
            foreach ( $breakpoints as $breakpoint ) {
                $target_price = $breakpoint->unit_price;
                $qty_threshold = $breakpoint->unit_break;

                // If the quantity matches this breakpoint, set the price and break the loop
                if ( $cart_qty <= $qty_threshold ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($target_price);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you. I had to remove if ($prices) {} as it was stopping the code from running, but otherwise it's working as intended now. There is the possibility of multiple currencies showing so thank you for that as well!

Comment: I know I've accepted the answer already, but now I'm noticing that if you go past the last breakpoint, the price is set to zero. Using the same array in my example, if I add 300000 to the cart, the price is .07 cents. If I have 300001 in the cart, the price resets to zero. I need it to stay at .07 for the last unit break and beyond.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out (seeing your answer). :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Kristián Filo's answer, I had to modify so that if the cart quantity is greater than the last breakpoint in the array, to use that last breakpoint price as it was resetting to zero.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'quantity_based_bulk_pricing', 9999, 1 );
function quantity_based_bulk_pricing( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) 
        return;

    // If you have multiple currencies in 'prices' meta, you should set target currency
    $target_currency = 'USD';

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // Get prices from post meta
        $prices = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'prices', true);
        $prices = json_decode( $prices, true );

        // Get cart item quantity
        $cart_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Loop through each currency
        foreach ( $prices as $currency => $breakpoints ) {
            // If this is not the target currency, continue
            if ( $currency != $target_currency ) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // get the last $qty_threshold and $target price in array
            $last_qty = end($breakpoints)['unit_break'];
            $last_price = end($breakpoints)['unit_price'];

            // Loop through each price breakpoint
            foreach ( $breakpoints as $breakpoint ) {
                $target_price = $breakpoint['unit_price'];
                $qty_threshold = $breakpoint['unit_break'];

                // If the quantity matches this breakpoint, set the price and break the loop
                if ( $cart_qty <= $qty_threshold ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($target_price);
                    break;
                }
                if ( $cart_qty >= $last_qty ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($last_price);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```